# SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 1,2,3,4

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How should my query look like?

I have:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '$var'`

`$var = "1,7,5,4,8,9";`

If is use this query only the first value from `$var` will be selected, "1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.

Try this query :

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE column in ($var);
```

[Reference-1](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Use `WHERE...IN` clause in query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN ($var)
```